# toolbox matlab giving warnings for nonexistance

Tags: matlab

When I start MatLab R2014a I get these warnings.  I just download it today and I need it for the optimization and symbolic toolbox.

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\lapack
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\distcomp\worker
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\filterdesign\filterdesign
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\filterdesign\quantization
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\physmod\simscape_language\simscape_language
```

There are more warnings than these, but I put only these.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with the installation (is C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\ where your MATLAB is installed?)

Comment: did you un-install previously installed toolboxes? Try running `rehash toolbox` (might wanna also try the other variations as well)... Also check you `path` contains only valid directories. If all fails, try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any of the missing toolboxes, you can remove the references to them, and hence the warnings, in `pathtool`.  If you're missing critical components, on the other hand, it looks like a reinstall is the only option.